# Change destination of uploaded file with Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using Multer to upload some files and I would like to upload files to different folders depending on which user uploads them.

This is my code:

**server.js**

```
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var teacher = require('./teachers.js');

router.post('/teachers/{id}/upload', teacher.uploadAvatar);
```

**routes/teachers.js**

```
var multer      = require('multer');
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/teacher/' }).single('avatar');

uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);

        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
}
```

Files are uploaded perfectly fine but I would like to create separate folders for each user. Folder name should be user's id. I can access user's id like this:

```
teacherId: req.params.id
```

Ideally, I also plan to rename uploaded file.

Answer (score 3):

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {

mkdirp('public/uploads/' + req.params.id , function(err) { 
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/' + req.params.id }).single('avatar');
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);

    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
});

});
}
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can't change the destination dynamically. You can move the files once they are updated. Please find the below issue and answer posted in github,

https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

You can use express router and in every route initialize new upload instance and use it as a middleware, example:

```
const createPost = require('./routes/createPost');

app.use('/create-post', createPost);
```

And then in routes/createPost.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/new_destination' });

router.post('/', upload.single('imageToPost'), async(req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(201);
});

module.exports = router;
```